# If a and b are matrices then what does a|b stand for?

Tags: matrices

Given $a =(1, 2, 3)^T$  and  $b = (5, 8, 4)^T$

what is $C=(a|b)$ mean?

is this a given $b$? or a over $b$? how to work out $C$?

Comment: When you have a question about notation like that it's best to indicate where you encountered this notation: which book, which class...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means augmented. So in this case:

$$
\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{a}|\mathbf{b}=\big[\begin{array}{c|c}\mathbf{a}&\mathbf{b}\end{array}\big]=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}1 & 5 \\ 2 & 8 \\ 3 & 4 \end{array}\right].
$$